# I need to run Multiple Correspondence Analysis from the prince package, but it seems to be broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to use the MCA of [the prince package](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince#multiple-correspondence-analysis-mca) and it fails to run the test example displayed in the documentation:

```
X = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/balloons/adult+stretch.data')
X.columns = ['Color', 'Size', 'Action', 'Age', 'Inflated']

mca = prince.MCA(n_iter=3, copy=True, check_input=True, engine='auto', random_state=42)
mca = mca.fit(X)


mca.plot_coordinates(x=X,
                     ax=None,
                     figsize=(6, 6),
                     show_row_points=True,
                     row_points_size=10,
                     show_row_labels=False,
                     show_column_points=True,
                     column_points_size=30,
                     show_column_labels=False,
                     legend_n_cols=1)
```

Simply copy-pasting this and trying to run it, throws:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prince/one_hot.py:31: FutureWarning: The SparseDataFrame class is removed from pandas. Accessing it from the top-level namespace will also be removed in the next version
  return pd.SparseDataFrame(

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-6fd265f4e0f4> in <module>
      3 
      4 mca = prince.MCA(n_iter=3, copy=True, check_input=True, engine='auto', random_state=42)
----> 5 mca = mca.fit(X)
      6 
      7 

~/anaconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prince/mca.py in fit(self, X, y)
     26 
     27         # Apply CA to the indicator matrix
---> 28         super().fit(self.one_hot_.transform(X))
     29 
     30         # Compute the total inertia

~/anaconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prince/one_hot.py in transform(self, X)
     29 
     30     def transform(self, X):
---> 31         return pd.SparseDataFrame(
     32             data=super().transform(X),
     33             columns=self.column_names_,

TypeError: SparseDataFrame() takes no arguments
```

Any idea what or where I need to change this to make it work? I desperately need to make that plot and I haven't found another package that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried using `prince` package for first time and had the same error running the examples from the README with a fresh install of anaconda `python 3.7` and most recent `prince/numpy/pandas/scikit_learn` stack. It seems to be an issue in `prince` with using a deprecated pandas class `SparseDataFrame`. There is an open issue https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince/issues/85. A workaround is to downgrade to `pandas-0.24.2`:

```
pip install pandas==0.24.2
```

This makes it work.